# Reserving RAM for OS on a CentOS server running MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos7

Given that a mongod process will consume quite a bit of the available RAM, is there a method to 'protect' a certain amount of RAM for the CentOS OS's use?

Or is this really even necessary from the OS's perspective...I assume like most operating systems, CentOS will take what it needs regardless.

I understand that if you are seeing this in practice, it's time to scale out/up...this is a purely theoretical question at this point as I am learning CentOS.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't manage memory.  It delegates the responsibility to OS.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't manage memory.  It delegates the responsibility to OS. It's beautifully explained in the below link.

[MongoDB Memory Management](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/alonhorev/mongo-world-2014withnotes)

Comment: Nice link, thanks! To clarify, I understand that MongoDB doesn't directly manage memory - my question is coming more from the Linux side, I suppose. Specifically, on CentOS is there a way to 'reserve' a minimum amount of RAM for the OS to prevent unnecessary RAM thrashing. For instance, SQL Server has a max server memory setting which slaps the SQL Server's hand if it tries to take more than 'x' MB of RAM. Since MongoDB does not have this type of configuration, I'm just wondering if there is a beneficial setting at the CentOS level that would protect some RAM from MongoDB processes

Comment: Frankly speaking,  I'm not that good at Linux flavors.  What I know from my experience is MongoDB uses free memory (unused by OS)  for its operations.  It could consume lot of RAM during index creation,  if you have too many client connections,  journal and working set. Answering your question,  in my project we have configured similar setting to identify the application using excessive resources and kill that process if it crosses the threshold.  But it is on AIX OS.  I'll check and let you know here.  But I think few such options could be possible for CentOS as well.